# divs next to each other, align to bottom

Tags: html, css

There are 3 divs next to each other:

```
<div style="left: float;">1</div>
<div style="left: float;">2</div>
<div style="left: float;">1</div>
```

which should looks like:

```
        content
        content
page 1  content  page 2
```

so page X should be aligned to bottom. I saw some "put relative to the parent, and absolute+bottom 0 for the child - aint no work!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Floats are a poor choice for this, you want your elements to be inline-block and adjust the vertical alignment:

http://tinker.io/f6b9e

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
}

<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>1</div>
```

Comment: Using _float_ is a good thing to do if you have IE8(or less) requierments. If not, _inline-block_ is the answer.

Comment: I hope it wont kills IE. It should run at least on IE7